# c++ struct not recognized

Tags: c++, struct

Im trying to process an array of structs but im recieving this error when accessing members: "must have class/struct/union"

```
struct person
{ int a; int b; int c;

}

person myArray[10];

int main()
{
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
   //Assume that connection string already established
   outdata<< myArray[i].a << myArray[i].b << myArray[i].c << endl;//Error occurs here when accessing the members within my array of structs
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: may i ask what is `var`? in `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Answer (score 9):

```
struct person { int a; int b; int c;  } ;
                                       ^^^^
```

You missed the `;`.

Answer (score 3):

You should do

```
struct person
{ int a; int b; int c;

} ;
  ^^^^

person myArray[10];
```

or

```
struct person
{ int a; int b; int c;

} myArray[10];
```

In the first case you defining a new type "person" (terminated by semocolon) and then declaring an array "myArray" of this new type "person".

In the second case you combine type declaration and variable definition which is allowed for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

1st correction:

```
   struct person
    { int a; int b; int c;

    } myArray[10];
```

2nd correction:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

`var` is not suported in c++. Instead you can use `auto` if you are running in VS2010 or above. Or else you will have to use `int`